# R Shiny use navbarPage together with conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Does R Shiny support use of conditionalPanels within navbarPage to load tabPanels i.e.

```
 shinyUI(navbarPage(
 collapsable=TRUE,
 title="Clinical Information Network",

 tabPanel("Home",
        fluidRow(
          uiOutput("userPanel")      

)),

conditionalPanel(
condition = "logged.in == T",

tabPanel("DQA",....)
) #End conditional panels
)) #End shiny UI
```

I've tried it out but it produces a garbled output. You can view the results at 41.220.124.237:3838 . I'm I doing it right?

Comment: You need to create the `navbarPage` using `renderUI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using this on the server.R:

```
output$secured <- renderUI({
  if(condition){
     tagList()
  }

})
```

And on the ui.R, just using the tag this way

```
uiOutput("secured")
```